# Hiding and displaying items in a table column above a threashold of lines

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap themed table, which has a column which can contain many line items. Is there a way to have it display a certain amount of lines, and have a "expand for more/hide for less" option to show the rest/hide the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find anything built-into bootstrap that will do exactly what you want.

This is pretty easy to accomplish with css and javascript. Use a class to set a `max-height` for the list. Then add a button with a click event to toggle that class.

https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/gmabfer6/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my-shortener .btn').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('td').toggleClass('short')
  })
})
```

```css
.my-shortener .list-group {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.my-shortener.short .list-group {
  max-height: 4rem;
}

.my-shortener .btn::before {
  content: "less";
}

.my-shortener.short .btn::before {
  content: "more";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>one</th>
            <th>one</th>
            <th>many</th>
            <th>one</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>one thing</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td class="my-shortener short">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li>one</li>
                <li>two</li>
                <li>three</li>
                <li>four</li>
                <li>five</li>
                <li>six</li>
              </ul>
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link"></button>
            </td>
            <td>another</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>one thing</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td class="my-shortener short">
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li>one</li>
                <li>two</li>
                <li>three</li>
                <li>four</li>
                <li>five</li>
                <li>six</li>
              </ul>
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link"></button>
            </td>
            <td>another</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, but how could be modified so it doesn't clip off the last line? Or in other words, the "more" starts after the last line precisely? I apologize for my utter ignorance in CSS. 

PS: Perhaps you could also recommend a resource or two so I learn to be more self-sufficient in CSS.

Comment: Or perhaps I need to just model it after my bootstrap theme specifics for the max-height value?

Comment: Also if no overflow is needed, can it not show the "more" line? Sorry for multi-adding...

Comment: You need to determine on your own what the `max-height` should be in order to suit your needs. You can use javascript to check the heights and remove the button when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, I can figure that. My JavaScript is better than my CSS. Much appreciated.